# Happy first birthday, Language Learning Stack Exchange!

Tags: discussion, birthday

A lot of us should have realized that yesterday marked this site's one year anniversary! As a user, I would first want to say that as a community, we are doing well for our first year though activity should be higher at this point to be honest. According to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning), we are not doing so good with activity in general:

[image]

We basically need more of everything right now. It is about now that we really need to start showing how well this site *is* and why it should graduate.

Personally, I think we should take a moment to thank our courageous moderators for keeping this site in check and setting an amazing example to everyone here. Thank you to:

- [Hatchet](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/85/hatchet)
- [Quill](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/8/quill)
- [Tom Au](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/46/tom-au)
- [Flimzy](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/13/flimzy)

Of course, we can't forget every other user here that contributed to this site in some way. Without this community, well, this site wouldn't be here the way it is now.

As a community, we have established and solved many key problems within our site, especially what is off and on topic here (the main issue everyone was worrying about at the start). We have also bonded a little more with everyone as people rather than users, a great aspect of really any SE sites. Yes, we have gone through up and downs but look where we are! A great beta site just waiting to be unleashed to the world.

We have also reached many landmarks throughout the year (too many to mention them all) like having a community blog to having 5 users reach 2k rep (two have reached 4k even)!

**More will be added...**

To summarize, happy birthday Language Learning Stack Exchange and I hope we will do better not just as individual users, but as a community if this site is to survive any longer. Remember to respect everyone and the policies created as they all built this site, piece by piece. I hope that next year, we will be so much more accomplished. If you have more to add, please put it in an answer!

## Happy birthday, Language Learning Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thanks for writing this post, Anthony! Thanks for you active contributions to the site, even when activity is low.

Comment: @Hatchet Right back at you! Thanks to you too!

Comment: Glad to see this post! Here's to hoping that we graduate in the next year!

Comment: And today we reached 2500 users.