# 1000 Days of Language Learning Stack Exchange!

Tags: discussion, site-activity, statistics

Our site has reached another milestone: on 31 December 2018 we have been in public beta for 1000 days! What have we achieved since the previous reviews at [500 days](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/569/800) and at [our first birthday](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/514/800)?

[image: Site statistics on Area 51; see the list below for the data in the iamge]

- **Questions per day**: 0.9 (compared to 0.9 at 500 days and 0.9 at 365 days). This number has not changed, even though it has gone up and down quite a lot. We even had periods with an average of 0.4 questions per day.
- **Percentage of questions answered**: 88% (compared to 91% at 500 days and 92% at 365 days). This number has steadily declined because we have accumulated [questions that are really hard to answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/unanswered), at least for our current participants.
- Users:

  - **Avid users**: 119 (compared to 92 at 500 days and 86 at 365 days): we are still making progress in this area.
  - **2.000+ rep users**: 6 (compared to 5 at 500 days and 5 at 365 days): five of our 2.000+ rep users joined the site during the first six months of the beta.
  - **3.000+ rep users**: 4 (compared to 3 at 500 days and 3 at 365 days): very few of the sites participants stick around long enough to reach this threshold.
- **Answers per question ratio**: 1.9 (compared to 2.0 at 500 days and 1.9 at 365 days): this has not changed significantly.
- **Visits per day**: 216 (compared to 96 at 500 days and 77 at 365 days). We have made significant progress in this area. Note that the site has consistently had more than 200 visitors per day since early September, with a peak of 294 visitors on 7-11 December 2018. During the end-of-year holidays, visits to the site always decrease a bit; it increases again in early January.

The site statistics on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) don't show the number of users on the site. The current number is 4.429, which is a significant increase since 20 August 2017 (our 500th day), when we had 2.699 users.

**Congratulations to all the participants for reaching this milestone and for contributing questions and answers!**

What would you like to add to this post? What important questions did the site solve for you? How can we improve and attract more users? Would you like to contribute to some of our [site promotion ideas](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/800)?

---

**Update**: Community moderator Shog9 posted additional statistics in [2018: a year in moderation](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/641/800).