# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Language Learning breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          6
Users destroyed                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            40         56
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                3         10
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          2         13
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                6         22
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                30        169
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               33         62
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                               12          0
Questions protected                               0          1
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         41
Questions closed                                 95          1
Question flags handled⁴                          33          8
Posts undeleted                                   0          3
Posts locked                                      0         14
Posts deleted⁵                                   21         75
Posts bumped                                      0         57
Comments flagged                                  0         87
Comments deleted⁶                               146         54
Comment flags handled                            82          5
Answers flagged                                   1         31
Answer flags handled                             26          6
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: "Questions close": 95 by moderators, 1 by the community. This confirms my impression that few *very* few questions get closed without moderator intervention. This even applies to questions that are very obviously off-topic (which I think is our most frequently used close reason).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe That is probably because some of our most active users happen to be moderators as well.

Comment: Yeah, I am one of the few non-moderators who votes to close. This is related to the general lack of activity on this stack.

Comment: Probably won't make this better, but... If even one non-moderator participates in closing a question, it counts as a Community close.

Comment: But I see [one](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3726) [two](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3794) [three](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3382) [four](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3388) [five](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3489) questions closed in 2018 where a non-mod participated in the closure. And that's only among those not yet deleted.

Comment: Oops, I got that backwards, @user4678: collaborative closures involving a mod count in the mod column *not* the community column. That'll teach me to trust my memory after four whiskies!